# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 when trying to compare a string to a string array in Hangman game

Tags: java, arrays, swing, netbeans

I'm making a Hangman game in Java for university coursework and I'm having problems with my code. I've got it to run and open but when I enter a letter into the text box to make a guess, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at hangman.HangmanFrame.guessButtonActionPerformed(HangmanFrame.java:164)
at hangman.HangmanFrame.access$000(HangmanFrame.java:14)
at hangman.HangmanFrame$1.actionPerformed(HangmanFrame.java:75)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6290)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6055)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2039)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4653)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2097)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4236)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4166)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2083)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2482)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:648)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:607)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:605)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:621)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:619)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:618)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Based on the first error in the list, I suspect it has something to do with this section of code:

```
    do
    {
        if (playerGuess.equals(arrayToGuess[c]))
        {
            correct = true;
            lettersToGet[c] = playerGuess;
        }

        c++;
    }
    while (c < 6);

    c = 0;
```

More specifically:

```
if (playerGuess.equals(arrayToGuess[c]))
```

I don't have a clue what is wrong with this as it's my first time working with String arrays and comparing the characters in each part of the array with what the user has entered. Hope someone can help. If you require any more information, let me know and I'll get back to you as soon as I can. I've also created a short-term Pastebin so the entire code can be viewed to help with spotting the problem: [Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/xg40gvPM)

Thanks

Comment: Where are you declaring and allocating `arrayToGuess`?

Comment: I am declaring it in `public class HangmanFrame extends JFrame` and allocating it in my `newGame();` method where the letters are put into each element of the array.

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means you are trying to access an illegal index of your array. This happens when  `c < 0` or when `c >= arrayToGuess.length`. Post the code where you create your array.

Comment: Can you please post the code? It's important which length you are setting for the array.

Comment: I create the array here:
`String word1 = "b.a.n.a.n.a";
    String word2 = "r.o.u.t.e.r";
    String word3 = "m.o.d.e.m.s";
    String word4 = "a.d.d.i.n.g";
    String word5 = "m.u.s.c.l.e";
    String word6 = "b.a.d.g.e.r";
    String word7 = "n.e.e.d.l.e";
    String word8 = "a.p.p.l.e.s";
    String word9 = "o.r.a.n.g.e";
    String word10 = "s.p.a.c.e.d";
    
    Boolean correct;
    
    String[] lettersToGet = new String[6];
    
    String wordToGuess;
    int maxGuesses = 10;
    int wrongGuesses = 0;
    String breaker = ".";
    String[] arrayToGuess = new String[6];`

Comment: @JoshHancock Where do you initialize `c`?

Comment: The exception tells you what index was out of bounds (in this case at index `0`). You posted how you are initializing your arrays, but just as important is the 'where'. You might want to amend your question to include all the necessary code.

Comment: In the `newGame();` method as it's used for my counter. Here is the entire code is that makes it easier to see [Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/xg40gvPM)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Also, please don't put code in comments, edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with `split` method - it splits String with reqexp and dot has special meaning, you have to set

```java
    String breaker = "[.]";
```

or

```java
    String breaker = "\\.";
```

btw: if you need to get i-th character of the String, you can use `s.charAt( i )` and you don't need split ;-)

Comment: You went through all that pastebin code? 1+ if just for the effort.